# Nuxt js high CPU usage on docker

Tags: docker, nuxt.js

I used nuxt and Docker to develop the app,
but running Docker uses a lot of RAM and CPU
Please see my configs below and tell me your opinion
Do you have a solution?

package.json File

```
  "name": "ladder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.ts,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --check .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js && yarn lint:prettier",
    "lintfix": "prettier --write --list-different . && yarn lint:js --fix",
    "test": "jest"
  },
}
```

nuxt.config.js File

```
  target: 'static',
  ssr: false,

  head: {
    title: 'ladder',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', content: '#007ad5' },
    ],
  },

  css: [
  ],

  plugins: [
  ],
  components: true,
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    '@nuxtjs/device',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    ['@nuxtjs/vuetify']
  ],
  modules: [
    'nuxt-route-meta'
  ],
  vuetify: {
    treeShake: true,
    defaultAssets: false
  },
  build: {},
  watchers: {
    webpack: {
      ignored: /node_modules/
    }
  },
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
  }
}
```

Dockerfile

FROM node:16

WORKDIR /portal
COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install
COPY . .

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn","dev"]

docker stats command
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITiwU.png)

Do you have a solution?

Comment: 1GB looks okay to me. Did you tried outside of docker?

Comment: The thing is that you run your instance in dev mode, you should build before and run with `npm run start`. 1GB is anything than okay. Nuxt needs normally around 40Mb of RAM